# How to test installation of Chef Server using ChefSpec?

Tags: chef

I'm getting started writing tests for my Chef cookbooks. I'm using [ChefSpec](http://code.sethvargo.com/chefspec/) to unit test my cookbooks. I need to install a Chef Server on one of my hosts and I would like to write a test for that. So far I have:

A ChefSpec test file in `spec/default_spec.rb`:

```
require 'chefspec'  
require 'chefspec/berkshelf'

describe 'my_chef_server::default' do
  let(:chef_run) { ChefSpec::Runner.new.converge(described_recipe) }

  it 'includes the chef-server recipe' do
    expect(chef_run).to include_recipe('chef-server')
  end
end
```

A `metadata.rb` file which declares that the `chef-server` cookbook is a dependency.

```
depends 'chef-server'
```

A `recipes/default.rb` which includes the `chef-server` recipe:

```
include_recipe 'chef-server'
```

When I run my tests (using `rspec`) I get an error:

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/folders/5g/dq2jk1sn30dgf7p4qhbvcjq80000gn/T/d20140429-77773-nxjusi/cookbooks/my_chef_server/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================

RuntimeError
------------
Could not locate chef-server package matching version 'latest' for node.

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/folders/5g/dq2jk1sn30dgf7p4qhbvcjq80000gn/T/d20140429-77773-nxjusi/cookbooks/chef-server/recipes/default.rb:31:in `from_file'
  /var/folders/5g/dq2jk1sn30dgf7p4qhbvcjq80000gn/T/d20140429-77773-nxjusi/cookbooks/my_chef_server/recipes/default.rb:11:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/folders/5g/dq2jk1sn30dgf7p4qhbvcjq80000gn/T/d20140429-77773-nxjusi/cookbooks/chef-server/recipes/default.rb:

 24:      node['chef-server']['nightlies']
 25:      )
 26:    unless omnibus_package
 27:      err_msg = 'Could not locate chef-server'
 28:      err_msg << ' pre-release' if node['chef-server']['prereleases']
 29:      err_msg << ' nightly' if node['chef-server']['nightlies']
 30:      err_msg << " package matching version '#{node['chef-server']['version']}' for node."
 31>>     fail err_msg
 32:    end
 33:  else
 34:    omnibus_package = node['chef-server']['package_file']
 35:  end
 36:  
 37:  package_name = ::File.basename(omnibus_package)
 38:  package_local_path = "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/#{package_name}"
 39:  
 40:  # Ensure :file_cache_path exists

F.

Failures:

  1) my_chef_server::default includes the chef-server recipe
     Failure/Error: let(:chef_run) { ChefSpec::Runner.new.converge(described_recipe) }
     RuntimeError:
       Could not locate chef-server package matching version 'latest' for node.
     # /var/folders/5g/dq2jk1sn30dgf7p4qhbvcjq80000gn/T/d20140429-77773-nxjusi/cookbooks/chef-server/recipes/default.rb:31:in `from_file'
     # /var/folders/5g/dq2jk1sn30dgf7p4qhbvcjq80000gn/T/d20140429-77773-nxjusi/cookbooks/my_chef_server/recipes/default.rb:11:in `from_file'
     # ./spec/default_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/default_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.28717 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/default_spec.rb:8 # my_chef_server::default includes the chef-server recipe
```

As far as I can tell, ChefSpec is correctly loading and executing my cookbook and running the dependent `chef-server` cookbook. However, the error shows that the `chef-server` cookbook is not able to install the latest chef-server package.

How should I write or mock my test so that I can correctly test that Chef Server is installed successfully?

Comment: It looks as though in order to avoid this exception during the chef-spec run you will need to mock out the OmnitruckClient class before calling converge on the runner.

Answer (score 1):

So this is largely due to a new instance of a class named `OmnitruckClient` [being created](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/chef-server/blob/101144b707f4d477ca7708c611abd1208e88c272/recipes/default.rb#L21) in the chef-server default recipe.
The OmnitruckClient is basically an HTTP call to the Omnitruck endpoint which is meant to return a URL where the chef-server recipe will then download the package from.

There's a couple of ways handling the testing of this behavior that I can think of.

Since the native ChefSpec virtual 'platform' is named `chefsepc`, the Omnitruck service will *never* respond with a correct URL link, so one method would be to supply a platform and version to the Spec test, which may have other values later on.

You can supply these selections in either the general configuration for RSpec, or per-test case (or even each converge).

I find it simplest to set these in the spec_helper.rb file. See [here](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec#configuration) for more on the configuration options.

Another mode may be to try mocking/stubbing out the OmnitruckClient class (or the Net::HTTP.get method it uses), but it seemed like this might be a little more confusing, and I couldn't actually get that to work yet.